# button on the NAV BAR is the wrong colour

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

I have got a navigation bar with a controller. I want an 'hamburger' icon on the right bar button.

[image]

Its an PNG file. 
When I add it on Interface builder its blue :(. 
I have been messing with the Tint colour and that changes the whole image. So if I want it green i just change the Tint color. But I want the colour to come from the png and not from the tint. I have tried using clear tint colour and that just makes it disappear. Any ideas on this quick one ?

Comment: Anyone with any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color with the PNG. As Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1):

> If you create a full-color template image, iOS ignores the color.

So you have to change it in the storyboard or programmatically, like this:

Tab Bar:

`UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()`

Navigation Bar:

`UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()`